# `require': incompatible library version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pg, gemset

I'm using RVM as version management for Ruby and installed Ruby 2.2.5. The bundle is installed completely and successfully. But when I started the rails server using rails s it is giving me 'require': incompatible library version (LoadError) for pg.

I tried re-installation of rvm many times. Cleaned the gemset but the issue still persists.

I'm getting the following error again and again:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/pg-0.19.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require': incompatible library version - /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/pg-0.19.0/lib/pg_ext.so (LoadError)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this link if you are using Ubuntu https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04#postgresql

Comment: It seems you are installing an incompatible version of the "pg" gem (postgres). Did you install postgresql first ?

Comment: @AlexanderLuna yes I have installed posgresql first. Even I tried to purge it completely and again try to install that but still the same issue.

Comment: Hi, did you find the issue?